# Can't remove empty space on SQL table using replace function

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, type-conversion

I received a csv file with a column called "Amount", which should be of a MONEY type inside my table.
First step I took was loading the csv file as is. So my table uses a string type for that Amount column, just because I know it will not be formatted as money on the source. Due to some spaces on that column, I can't convert from NVARCHAR to MONEY.

Here's the initial table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE #TestReplace (
    Amount NVARCHAR(100)
)
```

Here's an example to what the client inserted as value for the column:

```
INSERT INTO #TestReplace VALUES('2 103.74')
```

Because there is a space into that string, I need to remove it so I can convert it to the MONEY type.

However, if I try the REPLACE SQL function, nothing happens. It's like the value does not change

```
SELECT REPLACE(Amount, ' ','') FROM #TestReplace
```

Amount after the replace command is still: 2 103.74

Am I missing something that does not catch the space after the number 2? Is there a better way to remove that space and convert from NVARCHAR to MONEY?

Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a character that is not a space but looks like one.  If you are using 8-bit ASCII characters, you can determine what the value is using:

```
select ascii(substring(amount, 2, 1))
```

If this is an `nvarchar()` (as in your example):

```
select unicode(substring(amount, 2, 1))
```

Once you know what the character is, you can replace it.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Gordon's answer, once you know the integer ASCII/Unicode value, you can use that in the replace function with the CHAR() and NCHAR() functions like so:

```
--For ASCII:
REPLACE(Amount, CHAR( /*int value*/ ), '')

--For Unicode:
REPLACE(Amount, NCHAR( /*int value*/ ), '')
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for adding this to the previous answer. Thank you!